# mod_proxy and trailing slashes?

Tags: reverse-proxy, httpd, mod-proxy

We use httpd and mod_proxy as a reverse proxy in front of our different web servers.

We have our `www` subdomain pointed to the reverse proxy, and mod_proxy directs requests
from there.

I haven't been able to come up with a concise way of saying this, so I'll just show:

If we have a web site at http://blah.example.com/my-web-app, we'll usually add a
line like this to the reverse proxy:

```
ProxyPass   /my-web-app      http://blah.example.com/my-web-app
```

so that a user can go to `http://www.example.com/my-web-app`. When the path
component of the request (`/my-web-app` in this case) is the same on both the
reverse proxy, and the web server, the trailing slash will get added automatically,
just like if someone went straight to `http://blah.example.com/my-web-app`.

However, if the path components are different, e.g.:

```
ProxyPass   /my-web-app      http://blah.example.com/some-other-path
```

then the trailing slash does *not* get added.

Is this behavior normal?  Is there some configuration that could take care of
this?

Answer (score 3):

Read carefully the section on ProxyPass in Apache httpd documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).  You can likely get around this behavior by explicitly specifying the trailing / for both arguments of the ProxyPass directive

```
ProxyPass   /my-web-app/      http://blah.example.com/some-other-path/
```